# Example of function such that her Cesaro mean won't converge in $L^2$ norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm looking for an example of function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f \in L^{1}(-\pi;\pi)$, and $f$ being $2\pi$ periodic, such that the Cesaro Mean $\phi_{N}f$ is such that $\phi_{N}f(a)$  will not converge to $f(a)$ if $f \in L^{2}(-\pi;\pi)$, for $a \in (-\pi;\pi)$. 
Thank you!

Comment: By Cesaro means you mean the Cesaro means of its Fourier series?

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez By Cesaro mean I mean $\phi_{N}f(x)= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} F_{N}f(x)$ with $F_{N}$ the fourier serie of f.

Comment: Do you want $f\in L^1$ or $f\in L^2$?